# Remove grey space on upper keyboard (React Native - iOS)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

There is grey space on my react native application for iOS platform, like the image below :

[image]

How to remove grey space on upper keyboard (React Native - iOS) ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Did you tried `autocorrect={false}` on your textInput?

Comment: yes, i have tried it @Poptocrack, the grey space is different from autocorrect space

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using this :

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:NO];
```